# How to solve equations with unknown bases?

Tags: polynomials, recreational-mathematics, wolfram-alpha

My friend dared me to find rational solutions for these equations:

$$x+11y=100$$
$$xy=2$$

And he keeps claiming it's possible but even [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B11y%3D100,xy%3D2) disagrees.

---

Perhaps the base is wrong?

$$x+(b+1)y=b^2$$
$$xy=2$$

But then we have $2$ equations and $3$ unknowns, and I don't know how to tackle this.

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2B(b%2B1)y%3Db%5E2,xy%3D2) shows the solution $(x,y,b) = (1,2,3)$

But how do I get to them step by step?

Also, notice when I plug in the base, the wolfram misses the irrational $x,y$ solutions for base $10$ even thought I did not put any restrictions on the solutions. Why is that?

It only shows $-1$ and $3$ as solutions for $b$?

Comment: As shown in your Wolfram|Alpha link, your problem can be reduced to finding bases $b$ such that $\sqrt{b^4 - 8b - 8}$ is a rational number. I don't know how to solve it, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need
$$   (b+1)y^2 - b^2 y + 2 = 0  $$
to have a rational root, that is
 $$  b^4 - 8 b - 8 $$
a square. This is smaller than $$ \left( b^2 \right)^2. $$
It is larger than $$ \left( b^2 - 1 \right)^2 = b^4 - 2 b^2 + 1 $$
as soon as 
$$  2 b^2 - 8b - 9 > 0. $$
As  $$  2 \cdot 5^2 - 8 \cdot 5 - 9 = 1, $$ and this increases with $b,$
it is impossible for $  b^4 - 8 b - 8 $ to be a square when $b \geq 5.$
Your remaining possibilities are $b = 2,3,4.$

Comment: and $b=2$ of course is impossible since there is a 2 in the original equation :-)